# Does $f(at)-f(t) \to 0$ implies that $\lim_\limits{t\to\infty}f(t)$ exists?

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f:(0,\infty)\to\mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function such that for every fixed $a>0$, $$f(at)-f(t)\to 0,\qquad t\to\infty $$
Does it imply that $\lim_\limits{t\to\infty}f(t)$ exists and is finite?

Comment: No, take $f(t)=\log\log t$.

Comment: @Rahul That's not a comment, that's an answer. At least with a minor correction to make the domain $t\in(0,\infty)$.

Answer (score 5):

No, it doesn't. Consider $$f(t)=\log(\log(t+1))$$

Comment: Can you elaborate why the above difference tents to zero?

Comment: @AleksejsFomins what is the limit of $\frac{\log at}{\log t}$? What is $\log at$?

Comment: @AleksejsFomins Just insert and calculate, using well-known properties of the logarithms.

Comment: I see, it is quite simple

Comment: @Arthur: Thanks a lot!